# Evaluating a Series expansion of PolyLog function

Tags: series-expansion, special-functions

I am trying to evaluate an expansion of the following integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{p^4}{1+\exp\left({\frac{p^2}{2mT} - \frac{\mu}{T}}\right)}\, dp = A_0(m,\mu) + A_2(m,\mu)T^2 + \ldots
$$ 
in terms of a power series of T. When I evaluate the integral with

```
Integrate[p^4/(1 + Exp[p^2/(2 m T) - μ/T]), {p, 0, ∞}]
```

the result is expressed in terms of a PolyLog function,

```
-((3 Sqrt[π/2] PolyLog[5/2, -E^((μ/T))])/(1/(m T))^(5/2))
```

which is fine. I can plot the result as a function of T at low T, if I assume some numeric values for $m$ and $\mu$:

```
Plot[-((3 Sqrt[π/2] PolyLog[5/2, -E^((1/T))])/(1/(1 T))^(5/2)), {T, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Plot of a PolyLog]

However, I cannot get a power series expansion with respect to T;

```
Series[T^(5/2)*PolyLog[5/2, -E^((μ/T))], {T, 0, 4}]
```

leaves me with a PolyLog function:

```
PolyLog[5/2, -E^((μ/T))] (SeriesData[T, 0, {1}, 5, 9, 2])
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your function does *not* have a series expansion at that point to begin with.

Comment: @guess-who-it-is That's a good point, I didn't think about that. However, it seems to me from the plot that the function can at least be approximated by some series in T. Can I get that approximation somehow?

Comment: @ svavil : you can, in fact make an expansion but not at T=0 (where Exp[1/T] has an esential singularity) but at T=eps, where eps is a small number, like 0.01 or less. The resulting series is then numerically a very good approximation to the exact function. It's late now, and I have to leave. I can write an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @ svavil : much better, I have provided the exact expansion in my answer.

Comment: +1 because the problem leads us to very interesting areas of Mathematica and mathematics.

Comment: Well, the problem itself comes from theoretical physics, it's the low-temperature expansion for the energy of a Fermi gas. I know little about the polylogarithm, so I'll do my best to understand your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "low-temperature expansion for the energy of a Fermi gas" - no wonder a Fermi-Dirac function showed up as the result…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It came as a little surprise to me that in spite of the essential singularity of `Exp[1/T]` the expansion of the integral in powers of `T` about `T=0` exists. In fact it can be easily written down with the asymptotic expansion of the function `PolyLog[s,z]`  for `|z|-> oo`  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

In our case we have `z = - Exp[1/T]` and `s = 5/2` and the integral of the OP (with `m->1,\[Mu]->1`) is given by the expression

```
f = -(3 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2]) T^s PolyLog[s, -Exp[1/T] ]/.s->5/2
```

Skipping intermediate steps, the asymptotic expansion of `f` for `T->+0` up to the n-th term is then given by

```
fa[n_, T_, s_] := -3 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2]
   Sum[(-1)^k ((1 - 2^(1 - 2 k)) (2 \[Pi])^(2 k)
      BernoulliB[2 k]/((2 k)! Gamma[s + 1 - 2 k]) T^(2 k)), {k, 0, n}]
```

For `n = 3` we have symbolically (exactly)

```
fa[3, T, 5/2] // Distribute
```

$$\frac{4 \sqrt{2}}{5}+\frac{\pi ^2 T^2}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{7 \pi ^4 T^4}{240 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{31 \pi ^6 T^6}{2688 \sqrt{2}}$$

Numerically

```
% // N

(*
Out[100]= 1.13137 + 6.97886 T^2 - 2.00896 T^4 - 7.84001 T^6    
*)
```

Plotting things

```
Plot[{f[T, 5/2], fa[0, T, 5/2], fa[3, T, 5/2], fa[6, T, 5/2]}, {T, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 8}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Exact (blue) and asymtotic values of an integral\nn = 0 -> brown, n = 3 -> \
green, n = 6 -> red", AxesLabel -> {"T", "f[T]"}]    
(* "150626_Plot_exact and asymptotics.jpg" *)
```

[image]

Notice that the asymptotic expansion is good only for sufficiently small `T`. Also - as is common with asymptotic expansions - higher terms lead to worse approximation, and the series must be terminated if the terms start to grow.

This is the complete answer to your problem, but it remains open how useful this expansion is, because it works only for very small T. It might be better for practical purposes to use Alexei's Fitting or my proposal to make a series expansion about T = eps, where eps is a small number, as shown in EDIT #1 below.

**EDIT #1: series expansion about T = eps**

As the function is question

```
f[T, s]

(* Out[4]= -3 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] T^s PolyLog[s, -E^((1/T))] *)
```

cannot be expanded about `T=0` we shall expand about `T=eps`, a small number.
This expansion is

```
fx[T_, eps_, n_] := Series[f[T, 5/2], {T, eps, n}] // Normal
```

Taking `eps = 0.1` and `n = 3` we obtain

```
fx[T, 1/10, 3] // N // Chop

(* Out[11]= 1.20095 + 1.38711 (-0.1 + T) + 6.84111 (-0.1 + T)^2 - 1.05306 (-0.1 + T)^3 *)
```

Now let's make some plots for different values of eps comparing `f` and the series approximations.

```
With[{eps = 0.1}, 
 Plot[{f[T, 5/2], Evaluate[fx[T, eps, 1]], Evaluate[fx[T, eps, 2]], 
   Evaluate[fx[T, eps, 3]]}, {T, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Integral f (blue) and series expansion about T = eps = " <> 
     ToString[eps] "\nn = 1 -> brown, n = 2 -> green, n = 3 -> red", 
  AxesLabel -> {"T", "f(T)"}]]
(* 150626_Plot_eps_01.jpg *)
```

[image]

With `eps = 0.1` and keeping `n = 3` terms we get a fairly good approximation, except at `T` very close to `0` (here we shoud take the asymptotic expansion shown in the main body of the answer).

But let's take a smaller `eps` in order to hopefully improve the approximation

```
With[{eps = 0.01}, 
 Plot[{f[T, 5/2], Evaluate[fx[T, eps, 1]], Evaluate[0.1 + fx[T, eps, 2]], 
   Evaluate[0.2 + fx[T, eps, 3]]}, {T, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Integral f (blue) and series expansion about T = eps = " <> 
     ToString[eps] "\nn = 1 -> brown, n = 2 -> green, n = 3 -> red", 
  AxesLabel -> {"T", "f(T)"}]](* 150626_Plot_eps_001.jpg *)
```

[image]

Bad luck! We can see clearly that eps must not be too small. For `eps = 0.01` the expansion breaks down already for small values of `T`.

With `eps = 0.5` we reach almost complete coincidence:

```
With[{eps = 0.5}, 
 Plot[{f[T, 5/2], Evaluate[fx[T, eps, 1]], Evaluate[fx[T, eps, 2]], 
   Evaluate[fx[T, eps, 3]]}, {T, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Integral f (blue) and series expansion about T = eps = " <> 
     ToString[eps] "\nn = 1 -> brown, n = 2 -> green, n = 3 -> red", 
  AxesLabel -> {"T", "f(T)"}]]
(* 150626_Plot_eps_05.jpg *)
```

[image]

Conclusion: the series expansion of the integral about `T = eps` gives a very good approximation in the interval `0 < T < 1` with `eps = 1/2` (which is far from being small!) and n = 3.

**EDIT #2 : An exciting stroll through the hall of fame of mathematics**

As already mentioned in my comment, is was highly exciting for me to discover that this integral has relationsships to a vast amount of mathematical names, functions, and methods which start with Euler and Bernoulli but reach up to the present time.

I'd like to share my joy with you, giving a brief list of "buzz" terms (taken from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)

Fermi-Dirac distribution, Bose-Einstein distribution, Feynman diagrams, Hurwitz zeta, Lerch transcendent, Ernst Schrödinger's duplication formula, Benoulli numbers, Stirling numbers, Euler numbers, Euler Gamma function, Bernhard Riemann zeta function, Dirichlet (eta- and beta functions),  Jonquière (who introduced polylog in 1899), Erdélyi, Legendre chi function, Debye function, Hankel contour integral (Whittaker & Watson 1927), Abel-Plana formula, Hermite-type integral representation, harmonic number, Euler's transformation, Euler's reflection formula, polylogarithm ladders (K-theory and algebraic geometry. Polylogarithm ladders provide the basis for the rapid computations of various mathematical constants by means of the BBP algorithm (Bailey, Borwein & Plouffe 1997)), monodromy group for the polylogarithm (Heisenberg group)

Comment: Hmm, using the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Asymptotic_expansions), it seems the factor is supposed to be $(2\pi)^{2k}$? This is what I got: `fa[n_, T_, s_] := 3 Sqrt[2 π] Sum[(1 - 2^(1 - 2 k)) Zeta[2 k] (T^(2 k))/Gamma[s + 1 - 2 k], {k, 0, n}]`.

Comment: @J. M.: Thank you for pointing out the typo. You are right, 2k instead of k, I'll correct that.

Comment: @J. M.: correction done, answer can be upvoted again (IMHO it also contained valid ideas which should not be downvoted because of a typo ;-)

Comment: I hadn't upvoted yet, but I'll do so now. I had tried building a Padé approximant from your series, but the resulting rational functions had poles on the positive $x$-axis... :(

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze : Thanks. The exact asymptotic expansion was what I needed, and somehow I overlooked the expansion in terms of Bernoulli numbers and gamma function when I was reading about the polylogarithm. The expansion about T = eps is also a nice method.

Comment: @svavil, alternatively, if you know about the Dirichlet $\eta$ function, then the series looks like $$3\sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\eta(2k) T^{2k}}{\Gamma(s+1-2k)}$$

Comment: @J. M. That's a useful expansion. I wonder why Mathematica doesn't offer this kind of expansion when I ask for `Series[T^(5/2)*PolyLog[5/2, -E^((\[Mu]/T))], {T, 0, 4}]`.

Comment: @svavil, Surprisingly, *Mathematica* doesn't know everything about special functions... :) actually, I forgot about the expansion Herr Doktor Hintze used until now; it's actually one of the basic series for the Fermi-Dirac functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can fit it, if you like. It can be done as follows. First this is the integral:

```
 int = Simplify[
  Integrate[
   p^4/(1 + Exp[p^2/(2 m T) - μ/T]), {p, 0, ∞}], {m > 0,
    T > 0}]

(*   -3 Sqrt[π/2] (m T)^(5/2) PolyLog[5/2, -E^((μ/T))] *)
```

Let us change the variable: `T -> t*mu`:

```
 expr1 = int /. T -> t*μ

(*   -3 Sqrt[π/2] (m t μ)^(5/2) PolyLog[5/2, -E^((1/t))]   *)
```

One observs that there is a factor `(m*mu)^5/2`, and apart from that everything only depends upon `t`. Let us exclude the factor `(m*mu)^5/2` for the time being:

```
 expr2 = expr1 /. (m t μ) -> t

(*  -3 Sqrt[π/2] t^(5/2) PolyLog[5/2, -E^((1/t))]  *)
```

and make a list out of it:

```
lst = Table[{t, expr2}, {t, 0.01, 1, 0.02}] // Chop;
```

This list can be now fitted by a simple polynomial, where the second order is it is quite enough:

```
    model = a + b*t + c*t^2;
ff = FindFit[lst, model, {a, b, c}, t]
Show[{
  ListPlot[lst, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.015]],
  Plot[model /. ff, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]

(*  {a -> 1.12715, b -> 0.164711, c -> 6.21685}   *)
```

To visually inspect the fitting quality have a look at the plot, where points are those of the list and the solid line is the fitting result:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: @ Alexei Boulbitch : Thanks! I've tried using `FindFit`, but I failed to make a table of data points correctly. I hope I'll use this method now and then.