# Inverse of Poly Log function? Asymptotic behavior of Poly Log function?

Tags: special-functions, inverse

I am unable to answer important questions such as what is the inverse of PolyLog[3/2,z]? I mean can you express the solution to
w = PolyLog[3/2,z] (solve for z in terms of w) in terms of functions known to Mathematica?

Also what does the large z expansion of PolyLog[3/2,z] and PolyLog[5/2,z] look like?

Comment: I do not believe there is a closed form for the inverse of a polylogarithm, but it should not be too hard to construct series expressions: `InverseSeries[Series[PolyLog[3/2, x], {x, 0, 5}]] // Simplify`. As for asymptotics, have you already seen [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Asymptotic_expansions)?

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes I knew about the wiki. But my comment was in the context of Mathematica. The asymptotic expansion returns unevaluated rather than giving me the wiki answer. Is this also because I am using an outdated version of Mathematica?

Comment: No, I don't think *Mathematica* is smart enough to know the asymptotic expansion of the polylogarithm (see e.g. [this older thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86923)).

Comment: For the second part of your question, look here: http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/06/01/03/01/01/0005/